# syntax error @ casting new.value in table trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, syntax-error

is there any problem :

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE TRIGGER `UPD_after_financialStatus` AFTER UPDATE ON `financialStatus` 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE `@grossAmountTillNow` varchar(100);
SET @grossAmountTillNow = CONCAT(
    CAST(OLD.grossAmountTillNow AS varchar(50)),
    "---",
    CAST(NEW.grossAmountTillNow AS varchar(50)));
...
```

it says `Syntax error near 'varchar(50)),"---",CAST(NEW.grossAmountTillNow AS varchar(50))); SET @grossAmoun' at line 4`.
can you help please ?

Comment: Are you sure you can use `varchar` inside `CAST`? According to [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) you can't...

Comment: @Marco , we can use `CAST()` inside `TRIGGER`

Comment: @diEcho: yes, but IMHO `varchar` is not a valid dest type according to manual...

Comment: what is the datatype of `grossAmountTillNow`

Comment: try to write  `CHAR(50)` instead of `VARCHAR(50)`

Comment: At the end your concat string could be 103 chars long, so you'd better to increase `@grossAmountTillNow` size...

Comment: @diEcho : thanks,change it to `char`; it has worked. [remove this line : `DECLARE @grossAmountTillNow varchar(100);
`]<br>@Marco: why you say string should be 103 chars long ? can you explain please?

Comment: sorry dear users, how can i close this question; because i found answer by diEcho comment, and can't select right answer from comments, how can i do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Please compare:

```
SELECT CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS VARCHAR(50))
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VARCHAR(50))' at line 1

```
SELECT CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS CHAR(50))
```

> 2012-04-10 12:30:29

The allowed values are explained at [Cast Functions and Operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast).